# Tweening with AS3 AIR 3.2

Tags: actionscript-3, air, tween

So, I'm trying to do a simple tween in my AIR for android app,

I am targeting Air 3.2 for android, all works perfectly fine until I try and Tween an object.

if i try and import `flash.event.TweenEvent`, if fails.

Can you do tweens when targeting AIR for Android??

EDIT

here is my class file

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class AppName extends MovieClip {

    var a:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function AppName() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, added);
    }

    public function added(e:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED, added);
        with(a.graphics){
            beginFill(0xff9900,1);
            drawRect(0,0,100,100);
            endFill();
        }
        addChild(a);
        var b:Tween = new Tween(a,"x",null,a.x,200,1,true);
        b.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISHED, process);
    }

    public function process(e:TweenEvent):void {
        var c:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        with(c.graphics){
            beginFill(0xff9900,1);
            drawRect(0,0,100,100);
            endFill();
        }
        addChild(c);
    }
}
}
```

It's only when I add the event listener and function to handle the event that flash spits its dummy out. it says that there is an error within the line containing "public function process(e:TweenEvent):void {"

Comment: Are you using flash builder or the flash cs6 IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. I suggest using a tweening library [TweenMax](http://greensock.com). As it is a lot faster and easier than Flash's default tweening engine. What tool are you using to develop your application? That might give a clue about your problem source.

Comment: Depending on the app greensock's licensing may be an issue.

Comment: I'm using flash cs6, basically I've imported the tween and tween event classes, and I can write a tween, no errors thrown, but then when I try adding an EventListener, it says that "Tween", is not a compile time constant, and then starts trowing an error on the tween line as well?! ill have a look at using TweenMax.

Comment: Check if you're accidentely adding a listener to `Tween` class statically. Also post that part of your code, so I can help more..

Comment: I can't seem to find anything suspicious in your code. The only thing I'd try would be renaming the `process` method, if it's a system reserved keyword it may be causing trouble

Comment: I've got a feeling its flash itself, i have used the process keyword in many different projects. If i open a .fla file and its respective .as class files into flash; then open and close another .fla file, flash throws errors until i select the first .fla again. almost like it is targeting the closed .fla even though it has been closed. (not sure if any of that makes any sense)

Comment: I'm really speachless. Maybe the best thing would be reinstalling your Flash Pro.